# Answer or Call by Phone App always through loudspeaker mode

Tags: android, mode

I am using Samsung mobile devices in the elderly care industry. I need to distribute the device and design it so that incoming calls are always through loudspeaker mode.
I will use the phone app developed by Samsung on Samsung One UI (Android 13).

I asked Samsung engineers and they provided the following solution

> 1.Please refer to the following developer's comment and kindly respond to the customer.
> AudioManager.setSpeakerPhoneOn is not used anymore and is depricated.
> Also no other app can use setspeaker phone other than the OEM's telecom app.
>
> Please check CallAudioRouteStateMachine.java -> setSpeakerPhoneOn api and use
> setCommunicationDevice and getCommunicationDevice which can be used to turn switch speaker on/off/

But after trying it, I still can't succeed.
I would like to ask if there is a more correct way from here.